# How to get filename from a file object in PYTHON?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, flask, postman

I am using below code where I am using PUT api from POSTMAN to send a file to a machine hosting the api using python script

```
@app.route('/uploadFIle', methods=['PUT'])
def uploadFile():
    chunk_size = 4096
    with open("/Users/xyz/Documents/filename", 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                break
            f.write(chunk)
    return jsonify({"success":"File transfer initiated"})
```

Is there a way to get the original filename so that I can use the same while saving the file ?

Can do as below by passing name from PUT api itself, but is it the best solution ?

```
@app.route('/uploadFIle/<string:filename>', methods=['PUT'])
def uploadFile(filename):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I achieved it using flask -

1. Choose form-data under body in POSTMAN
2. You can give any key, i used 'file' as key, then choose option 'file' from drop down arrow in key column
3. Attach file under 'value' column and use below code to get the file name -

   ```
    from flask import request
    file = request.files['file']
    file_name = file.filename
   ```